# Minipage - creating two alligned colored boxes

Tags: boxes, two-column

I want to divide my page into two colored columns with equal width. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}
    {
        \begin{minipage}{0.5 \textwidth}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        \end{minipage}  
    }
    \fcolorbox{red}{blue}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5 \textwidth}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        \end{minipage}  
    }
\end{document}
```

And this is the output: 
[image] 
I have no idea what can have gone wrong. Why did these boxes change their position?

Comment: One `minipage` has `[t]`op alignment, the other has default central alignment (thus the center of the left box is aligned with the top of the right box).  You will instead want both `minipage`s to have the same alignment, whether it is `[t]` or `[b]` is for you to decide.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes 
Thanks, this solved my problem. I think your comment should qualify as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, one `minipage` has `[t]`op alignment, the other has default `c`entral alignment (thus the center of the left box is aligned with the top of the right box).

You will instead want both `minipages` to have the same alignment, whether it is `[t]` or `[b]` is for you to decide. In the MWE below, I show both possibilities for boxes of different overall heights.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\data[1][c]{
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[#1]{0.5 \textwidth}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}  
    }
    \fcolorbox{red}{blue}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[#1]{0.5 \textwidth}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        \end{minipage}  
    }
}

\data[t]\clearpage\data[b]
\end{document}
```

[image]